# Python process text file with these criteria

Tags: python, string, io, strip

I am trying to clean a text file with some criteria.

My text shows like this

> NHIST_0003 (ZS.MC.BGE.0424SPVCOS)          (21.12) 14.08 
>   (ZS.MC.BLK.0424SPVCOS)          (21.12) 14.08 
>   (ZS.MC.GRY.0424SPVCOS)          (21.12) 14.08 
>   (ZS.MC.BLK.0525SPVCOS3)         (21.12) 14.08 
>   (ZS.MC.GRY.0525SPVCOS2)         (21.12) 14.08 
>   NHIST_0004 (ZS.MC.BGE.0424SPVCOS)           (21.12) 14.08

I need to remove whatever text is ahead of the first "(" parenthesis if the line has any text before as well as remove the parenthesis of the text I want to keep. I also need to get rid of the numbers with parenthesis inside. looking at row number one, I only want to keep

> ZS.MC.BGE.0424SPVC0S   14.08

These are codes I came up with trying to tie things up. I would prefer not to use re expressions because is too advance for me at this stage.

```
fileName='reach.txt'
fileName2='outreach.txt'


while True:
    f=open(fileName,'r')
    for words in f:
        x=words.split('(', 1)[-1]
        g = open(fileName2,'w')
        g.write(x)
        g.close()
```

This loop is infinite. I thought that by closing the file, I was telling the system to stop processing lines.

Comment: `with open(file, 'r') as fh: for row in fh: row[:row.find('(')]` or just do `row.split()` and take the pieces you want. for instance `x = row.split()` and `x[1], x[3]`

Comment: but would x = row.split() and x[1], x[3] work even if the text file is not formatted the same all throught?

Comment: It didn't, so i reworked the code to find `(...)` and then take the last item in the row because that appears to be consistent.

Comment: Tried my latest edit, and the result matches your "i want this result" :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop through the lines in a file like this:

```
with open('filename.txt') as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        #do stuff
```

To take the information from a line that you want, you can do this:

```
cleaned = []
items = line.split()
for item in items:
    if item.startswith('(') and item.endswith(')'):
        cleaned.append(item.strip('()'))
        break
cleaned.append(items[-1])
cleaned = ' '.join(cleaned)
```

Full program:

```
in_file = 'reach.txt'
out_file = 'outreach.txt'

def clean(string):
    if not string:
        return string

    cleaned = []
    items = string.split()
    for item in items:
        if item.startswith('(') and item.endswith(')'):
            cleaned.append(item.strip('()'))
            break
    cleaned.append(items[-1])
    return ' '.join(cleaned)

with open(in_file) as i, open(out_file, 'w') as o:
    o.write('\n'.join([clean(line) for line in i]))
```

Comment: or just `for line in f`, same thing. Also this gives syntax error because of missing `:` (fixed that for you)

Comment: Brilliant!! thanks so much. I like how you wrote it. Is very readable and simple.

Comment: Scorpion_God like that code but is prompting an out of index error

Comment: it says line 16 and 11

Comment: @weemo so you also have blank lines in your text file then? It now works with blank lines.

Comment: Yes I do. let me try . Thx

Answer (score 0):

```
fileName='reach.txt'
fileName2='outreach.txt'

def isfloat(s):
    try:
        float(s)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False

g = open(fileName2, 'w')
with open(fileName, 'r') as fh:
    for row in fh:
        x = row.split()
        for item in x:
            if '(' in item and ')' in item:
                first = item.strip('()')
                break
        for i in range(-1, 0-len(x), -1):
            second = x[i]
            if isfloat(second):
                break
        print(first, second)
        g.write(' '.join((first, second)) + '\n')
g.close()
```

Which gives:

```
ZS.MC.BGE.0424SPVCOS 14.08
ZS.MC.BLK.0424SPVCOS 14.08
ZS.MC.GRY.0424SPVCOS 14.08
ZS.MC.BLK.0525SPVCOS3 14.08
ZS.MC.GRY.0525SPVCOS2 14.08
ZS.MC.BGE.0424SPVCOS 14.08
```

There we go, this code will handle all kinds of faults in the data.
For instance, if the floating value isn't at the very end that will be covered as well, if the `(...)` data isn't fixed in lets say the second position but the first, that will be covered as well.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using regular expressions if every line has something like `(code you want) (thing you don't want)`.

```
import re
infile = 'reach.txt'
outfile = 'outreach.txt'

with open(infile, 'r') as inf, open(outfile, 'w') as outf:
    for line in inf:
        # each line has "* (what you want) (trash) *"
        # always take first one
        first = re.findall("(\([A-z0-9\.]*\))", line)[0]

        items = line.strip().split(" ")
        second = line[-1]
        to_write = " ".join((first, second))
        outf.write(to_write + "\n")
```

The regex `"(\([A-z0-9\.]*\))"` matches any combination (denoted by `[ ]*`) of:

- letters (`A-z`),
- numbers (`0-9`), and
- period (`\.`)

that is inside parentheses (`\( \)`).

From your example, there will always be two matches, something like `ZS.MC.BLK.0424SPVCOS` and `21.12`. `re.findall` will find both of these in the order given.  Since the one you want is always first, grab that with `re.findall(regex, line)[0]`.

Comment: cant get re just yet. Too advance for me. Read about it I just dont get the wildcards

Comment: @weemo `.` just means any character. So `'a..'` would match any three character string that starts with `'a'`.

Comment: Thanks for all these..will take each and read through...Really appreciate the feedback

Answer (score 0):

```
blacklist = set('1234567890.')
with open('reach.txt') as infile, open('outreach.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    for line in infile:
        line = line.strip()
        if not line:
            continue
        _left, line = line.split("(", 1)
        parts = [p.rstrip(")").lstrip("(") for p in line.split()]
        parts = [p for i,p in enumerate(parts) if not all(char in blacklist for char in p) or i==len(parts)-1]
        outfile.write("%s\n" %(' '.join(parts)))
```

With your example `reach.txt`, I get

```
ZS.MC.BGE.0424SPVCOS 14.08
ZS.MC.BLK.0424SPVCOS 14.08
ZS.MC.GRY.0424SPVCOS 14.08
ZS.MC.BLK.0525SPVCOS3 14.08
ZS.MC.GRY.0525SPVCOS2 14.08
ZS.MC.BGE.0424SPVCOS 14.08
```

Comment: ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack

Comment: @weemo: show me the input. I suspect an empty line at the end of your file. If so, the edit should help

Comment: anyway I can post the whole text file? is 4,000 lines. Does not strictly follows a format unfortunately

Comment: @weemo: we need a minimal working example. So either post a spanning set of all possible lines in your OP or describe all possibilities so that a more robust solution can be offered